# How to convert context.universe.Annotation to MyAnnotation in a Scala Macro

Tags: scala, macros, annotations

I am on Scala 2.11.1, I have an annotation

```
case class MyAnnotation(id: String, message: String) extends StaticAnnotation
```

I would like to create a macro `MessageFromMyAnnotation` that transform the following code

```
class Foo {
    @MyAnnotation("001", "James Bond 001")
    def foox = {
        ... // my messy code
        val x = MessageFromMyAnnotation("001")
        ... // my messy code
    }
}
```

to

```
class Foo {
    @MyAnnotation("001", "James Bond 001")
    def foox = {
        ... // my messy code
        val x = "Hello world, James Bond 001"
        ... // my messy code
    }
}
```

In brief, the macro find, on its enclosing element, a `message` of `@MyAnnotation` whose `id = "001"` and return `"Hello world, " + message`

This is the macro

```
object MessageFromMyAnnotation {
    def apply(id: String) = macro impl
    def impl(c: Context)(id: c.Expr[String]): c.Expr[String] = {
        c.internal.enclosingOwner.annotations.filter( anno =>
          anno.tpe =:= c.universe.typeOf[MyAnnotation] &&
          anno.asInstanceOf[MyAnnotation].id == id.value //this does not work
        ) match {
            case anno :: Nil => c.universe.reify("Hello world, " + ...)
            case x => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, c.universe.showRaw(x))
        }
    }
}
```

I want to convert `anno` of type `cuniverse.Annotation` to `MyAnnotation` and compare its `id` with the argument `id` of type `c.Expr[String]`, but the `anno.asInstanceOf[MyAnnotation]` yields a `ClassCastException` and `id.value` gives me an error message

```
cannot use value except for signatures of macro implementations
```

So, please help me with 2 questions:

- How to convert `anno` of type `cuniverse.Annotation` to `MyAnnotation`
- How to compare its `id` with the argument `id` of type `c.Expr[String]`

Comment: You don't have an instance of `MyAnnotation` - this is compile time, you only have an AST that represents the call. You can get the `Expr` that's the parameter given to the `cuniverse.Annotation`, and either splice it, or pattern match it as a String literal and then take the value out of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully made it thanks to @Imm's suggestion:

```
You don't have an instance of MyAnnotation - this is compile time, you only 
have an AST that represents the call. You can get the Expr that's the 
parameter given to the cuniverse.Annotation, and either splice it, or pattern 
match it as a String literal and then take the value out of that.
```

And here is the code

```
object MessageFromMyAnnotation {
  def apply(id: String) = macro impl
  def impl(c: Context)(id: c.Expr[String]): c.Expr[String] = {
    import c.universe._
    id match { case Expr(Literal(Constant(idVal: String))) => 
      (for { Annotation(tpe, 
             Literal(Constant(annoIdVal: String)) :: 
             Literal(Constant(annoMessageVal: String)) :: 
             Nil, _) <- c.internal.enclosingOwner.annotations
             if tpe =:= typeOf[MyAnnotation] && idVal == annoIdVal
           } yield (annoIdVal, annoMessageVal)
      ) match {
        case (annoIdVal, annoMessageVal) :: Nil => 
          reify(c.literal("Hello world, " + annoMessageVal).splice)
        case matchedMore :: thanOne :: Nil => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Found more than one @MyAnnotation with the same id")
        case x => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Not Found @MyAnnotation with the specified id")
      }
    }
  }
}
```